# Debug app bundle not signed - internal testing in Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I was trying to upload my debug .aab file to internal testing in Play Console, but it gives me the well-known 'The Android App Bundle was not signed" error message. When I try to upload the release .aab file it works perfectly. I followed the Flutter documentation about releasing an app and as I said my application is signed.

This is my build.gradle file:

```html
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
  ...

  signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do? I am using AdMob in my application, and I think I should not test the application with real ads, so I have to use debug build variant.

Comment: You can not upload file to Google Play signed by debug key.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing. Good to know, you always learn something new. :)

Comment: I've tried creating a debugable build with my real release key and it still says "The Android App Bundle was not signed"